# bar graph (barplot) subdivided with standard error and 3 variables (Stage x Dose x mortality) and factors levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

Good Night Masters!

I would like to make a subdivided bar chart with standard error, but I am having difficulty because of my large amount of data, and I am unable to adjust and do.
I have insect stage data (eggs, larvae, pupae and male and female adults). Photo below.

[image]

So I thought of dividing each stage by each chart, but I couldn't make the chart: The code I used was this:

```
data <- read.table (file.choose (), header = TRUE)
attach (data)
head (data)
if (! require ("pacman")) install.packages ("pacman") pacman :: p_load (readr, dplyr, ggplot2)

# Grouping according to treatment. Applies the sum of all observations (mortality) according to the clustering factor.

total_trat <- data%>%
              group_by (dose)%>%
              summarize (Stage = sum (mortality, na.rm = T))
              total_trat

#To make the chart
ggplot (total_trat_local, aes (Dose, Mortality)) +
geom_col (alpha = 0.8, position = "dodge") + 
facet_wrap (~ Stage) +
theme_bw (16) +
theme (axis.text.x = element_text (angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust =   1))

# Deviation (SD)
 media_trat_desv <- data%>% group_by (Dose)%>% 
 summarize (dev = sd (mortality, na.rm = T) / sqrt (n()), galls = mean (mortality, na.rm = T))
 media_trat_desv

 #Standard deviation as a function of each Dose and Stage.
 mediana_trat_Stage_desv <- data%>% filter (Collection == 5)%>% group_by (Dose, Stage)%>% 
 summarize(dev = sd (mortality, na.rm = T) / sqrt (n ()), mortality = median (mortality, na.rm = T))
 mediana_trat_Stage_desv

 # subdivided chart
  ggplot (median_trat_Stage_desv, aes (Dose, mortality)) +
  geom_col (alpha = 0.8, position =  "dodge") + 
  geom_errorbar (aes (ymin = mortality - dev, ymax = mortality + dev), width = 0.4, alpha =  0.8) + 
  facet_wrap (~ Stage) + theme_bw (16) + theme (axis.text.x = element_text (angle = 45, hjust = 1,  vjust = 1))
```

I would like to get the chart below:

[image]

But on my R it goes like this:

[image]

Thanks!!

## The data are project are below: dput(head(dados, 30))

`dados <- structure(list(Dose = structure(c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c    ("AdultsF_0Control", 
"AdultsF_10Gy", "AdultsF_15Gy", "AdultsF_20Gy", "AdultsF_5Gy", 
"AdultsM_0Control", "AdultsM_10Gy", "AdultsM_15Gy", "AdultsM_20Gy", 
"AdultsM_5Gy", "Eggs_0Control", "Eggs_10Gy", "Eggs_15Gy", "Eggs_20Gy", 
"Eggs_5Gy", "Larvae_0Control", "Larvae_10Gy", "Larvae_15Gy", 
"Larvae_20Gy", "Larvae_5Gy", "Pupae_0Control", "Pupae_10Gy", 
"Pupae_15Gy", "Pupae_20Gy", "Pupae_5Gy"), class = "factor"), 
Stage = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Adults_Female", "Adults_Male", 
"Eggs", "Larvae", "Pupae"), class = "factor"), mortalidade = c(133L, 
136L, 130L, 156L, 155L, 146L, 144L, 130L, 132L, 133L, 104L, 
123L, 118L, 121L, 114L, 94L, 96L, 86L, 100L, 99L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 137L, 120L, 35L, 10L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Can you post a sample data? Otherwise, you are unlikely to receive any help. SO users are trying to help people, but they do not necessarily have time to type your data in the picture.

Comment: I recommend you to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks Jazzurro and I'm sorry again!

Comment: No worries. Hope you can arrange a sample data for SO users.

Comment: Very thanks bro, edited the post and inserted the sample data now.

Comment: Is `dados` identical to `data` in your code?

Comment: I wonder if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842923/specify-error-bars-with-ggplot-and-facet-grid) helps you. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872951/how-do-i-add-se-error-bars-to-my-barplot-in-ggplot2) is also similar to the previous question.

Comment: I tried to do this graph too, but it didn't work out as much as the one I posted! However I try again with these scripts

Comment: `ggplot(dados, aes(x = Dose, y = mortalidade)) + stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun.y = mean, position = "dodge") + stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, position = "dodge") + facet_wrap (~ Stage) + theme_bw (16) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text (angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1))` It seems that this code is producing what you are after.

Comment: Thank you bro worked perfectly, I even managed to make the graphics that I had failed to do earlier.